# DAX AVERAGE() function differs from table average of column

Tags: powerbi, dax

I am new to DAX and running into a problem with regard to averages.

In PowerBI I am using a table with some dimensions and measures, the measures obviously require some form of summary so the dimension can roll up/summarize the data.

The problem is, I have a measure let's call Minutes that I want to average across the 5 lines of data, I drag the column minutes on set the summary in the table to average and it works perfectly by splitting the data according to the dimensions - data example:

```
 1. A 10
 2. A 8
 3. A 10
 4. A 7
 5. A 5
 6. B 10
 7. B 10
 8. B 9
 9. B 9
 10. B 10

Output in Table:

 1. A 8
 2. B 9.6
```

If I want to use that Average of 8 and 9.6 in another calculation and I create a new column called AvgMins = AVERAGE(Minutes) and drag it onto the grid I get a value of 8.8 for both A and B - I understand that the most likely reason for this is due to the calculation happening before the dimension splits and therefore the grid can't handle it - but how do I handle this in the DAX column calc itself?

As pointed out by Jos I was creating the calculation as a column instead of a measure, changing to a measure the normal AVERAGE() works perfectly

Comment: What exactly is your desired output?

Comment: You say "*I create a new **column** called AvgMins*", but you should be creating a **measure**.

Comment: @JosWoolley - that is exactly the problem, I was trying to create it as a column, instead of a measure, the normal AVERAGE() works fine - thank you so much!

Comment: @DevinSmith, could you please extend your post with some screenshots of your tables to make it more recognizable by the users who will run into the same problem?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: @JosWoolley, could you please put your comment in the form of an answer, and, if you don't mind, extending it with a screenshots as well, so we could upwote it, and the author could mark it as a solution?
Thank you in advance too!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be using a *Measure*, not a *Calculated Column*.

Answer (score 1):

A measure can result in a lot of different numbers - depending on the filter context.

```
AbgMins = AVERAGE('Table'[Minutes])
```

w/o any filter will return the average of the Minutes column, which is 8.8. But if you filter it by your category - A and B - it will return the average for all A's and all B's, which is 8 and 9.6.

Comment: Nope that doesn't work - the above calc is what I have used and it defaults the amount to a fixed amount even though the dimensions differ - I want it to differ per dimension like it does when I drag it onto the grid and set the summary to average

Comment: Of course it doesn't work! But where's your question then? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: As stated in my question the in table calculation works perfectly by splitting and then averaging per dimension, I need to achieve the same in a dax calculation so that I can do further calculations on the measure - the problem is the dax AVERAGE() calc is not taking the dimensions into account when calculating

Comment: What further calculation do you have in mind? Could you give an example? The filter context is important in DAX.

Comment: Jos mentioned I am using a column instead of a measure, and he is 100% correct, I changed my use to a measure and the normal average works without any additions - feel like a clutz!

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for Average of Average.

```
AVERAGEX(
    VALUES('Table'[CategoryColumnName])
    ,CALCULATE(AVEARGE('Table'[Minutes]))
    )
```

This if you are looking for Average per category

```
CALCULATE(
    AVERAGE(
        AVEARGE('Table'[Minutes]))
        ,ALLEXCEPT('Table','Table'[CategoryColumnName])
    )
)
```